# Spring Boot returns login page instead of styles

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot app and for some reason each request from client to `css` files receives HTML of login page in response. No error, no redirect, status is 200 and HTML is in response body. What can be the reason of it?

Login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link th:href="@{/css/login.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-group outlet">
    <p>Sign in</p>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div><input name="username"/></div>
        <div><input name="password" type="password"/></div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${loginError}"><p>Invalid username or password</p></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    //TODO: fix this
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                    .failureUrl("/login-error")
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Login controller:

```
@Controller("login")
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String postLogin() {
        // TODO
        return "/welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login-error")
    public String loginError(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Type:text/css;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 23 Nov 2017 17:17:59 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

[image: Folder structure:]

**UPD:**
An important thing to notice is that if I don't explisitly use permitAll() on /css/**, then I get 302 and redirect to login page. If I do, then I get 200 and content of login page in response body instead of actual content of css file

**UPD 2:**
Debug logs from spring security during request to login page, which should have the styles:

```
2017-11-24 17:43:33.926 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.927 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.938 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2017-11-24 17:43:33.938 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2017-11-24 17:43:33.941 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.942 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@f14213c
2017-11-24 17:43:33.942 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.943 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.944 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-11-24 17:43:33.944 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.944 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2017-11-24 17:43:33.944 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.944 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.946 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.947 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.947 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.947 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID 3A4BF8C25F0B7B63F9906222B94C800A is invalid.
2017-11-24 17:43:33.948 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.948 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-11-24 17:43:33.950 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [permitAll]
2017-11-24 17:43:33.955 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2017-11-24 17:43:33.963 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7f46f895, returned: 1
2017-11-24 17:43:33.963 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2017-11-24 17:43:33.963 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2017-11-24 17:43:33.963 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2017-11-24 17:43:34.826 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2017-11-24 17:43:34.862 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2017-11-24 17:43:34.862 DEBUG 4088 --- [io-1488-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2017-11-24 17:43:35.015 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.015 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.015 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2017-11-24 17:43:35.016 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7582e3b6. A new one will be created.
2017-11-24 17:43:35.016 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.016 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@f14213c
2017-11-24 17:43:35.016 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.016 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.016 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /css/login.css' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-11-24 17:43:35.016 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /css/login.css' doesn't match 'POST /login
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fa8940c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EACE11EC21F40FE5BD10CC56F71C0DD3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.017 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/css/login.css'; against '/css/**'
2017-11-24 17:43:35.019 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /css/login.css; Attributes: [permitAll]
2017-11-24 17:43:35.019 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fa8940c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EACE11EC21F40FE5BD10CC56F71C0DD3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2017-11-24 17:43:35.021 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7f46f895, returned: 1
2017-11-24 17:43:35.021 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2017-11-24 17:43:35.021 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2017-11-24 17:43:35.021 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/login.css reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2017-11-24 17:43:35.031 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2017-11-24 17:43:35.033 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2017-11-24 17:43:35.033 DEBUG 4088 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**UPD 3:**
Debug logs of MVC seem fishy, why does it map the request to `login.css` to my login controller?

```
2017-11-24 19:05:13.967 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/css/login.css]
2017-11-24 19:05:13.967 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /css/login.css
2017-11-24 19:05:13.968 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String zhi.yest.furniture.controller.LoginController.login()]
2017-11-24 19:05:13.968 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/css/login.css] is: -1
2017-11-24 19:05:13.969 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/css] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2017-11-24 19:05:13.969 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : Found matching bean for view name 'login' - to be ignored since it does not implement View
2017-11-24 19:05:13.969 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'login.css'
2017-11-24 19:05:13.970 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : No acceptable view found; returning null
2017-11-24 19:05:13.970 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : Found matching bean for view name 'login' - to be ignored since it does not implement View
2017-11-24 19:05:13.970 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@6cb35f4f] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-11-24 19:05:13.979 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-1488-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: You didn't configure a path attribute in `GetMapping`. Did you try `@GetMapping("/login")`?

Comment: @dur adding `@RequestMapping("/login")` to controller class solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First try setting property for debug mode logging and verify it but i'm quite sure it's because you are trying to get resource as anonymous user, try replacing .permitAll() with .anonymous()

Comment: same result with anonymous()

Comment: @Override 
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception { 
web .ignoring() .antMatchers(&quot;/resources/**&quot;); 
 }

Comment: Sorry for the format but i have no idea how to set it properly from android app

Answer (score -1):

Try to override the `configure(WebSecurity web)` method in your SecurityConfig.

Also, you can try to change in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` the paths of the static folders (so you will be able to have an access to them from thymeleaf templates with `@{/css/main.css}`):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired
 private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

 // fix this
 @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
 web
    .ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/resources/static/**", "/resources/templates/**");
 }

 // fix this
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/css/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                .failureUrl("/login-error")
                .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
}
```

Comment: All of that has already been suggested and none of that changes the behavior